# Automating multiple form submissions with Liferay Portal and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, junit, liferay

I've had a whale of a time attempting to figure this out, considering the limited documentation that I can find outside of the API itself.

I have a liferay portlet that simply clicks on a button, pops up a form with a bunch of fields, and then submits that form.

I want to use Selenium (or really any automation tool that can do this with Liferay) to similuate 100-500 concurrent submissions.

Has anyone used Selenium with LifeRay in a similar manner?

Comment: I don't think Selenium is intended for load testing. Why don't you just write a test case to simulate the 100-500 POST requests generated on submit?

Comment: That's certainly a "can do". I can easily write a test that simulates all middle/back end functionality required for a complete form submit. I am curious more about the front end aspect of it - simulating the button clicks, submits, and form validation.

Comment: Have you gone through the liferay source code, they have test cases written which do something similar. Hope that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is a good tool to test the correctness of you web system, NOT to test the permormace of this system. For Stress testing you should use another tool, like JMeter http://jmeter.apache.org/ . Or you can code test script with HtmlUnit http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/